# User role weaker than authenticated user

Tags: users

I am using LoginToboggan Module and I want to create to create a "pre-authenticated" user role that users get assigned to upon registration. After they have verified their email address they will be promoted to "authenticated" users. Obviously, pre-authenticated users should have restricted permissions.

> If "Set password" is selected, users will be able to login before their e-mail address has been authenticated. Therefore, you must choose a role for new non-authenticated users -- you may wish to add a new role for this purpose. Users will be removed from this role and assigned to the "authenticated user" role once they follow the link in their welcome e-mail.

I created a new role "pre-authenticated" and gave it weight 1 and "authenticated" weight 2 ("anonymous" has weight 0 and "administrator" has weight 4). However, whenever I give "authenticated" users the permission to do something, "pre-authenticated" users inherit this permission. It seems like Drupal treats all custom roles as being extra roles for users that already are authenticated. I already cleared my cache and ran cron.

Comment: if you give a user "pre-authenticated" role then the user is already an "authenticated" user.

Comment: ^this.  You'd be better off using the autheticated user role as the pre-authnticated role, and then setting up another role for "authorised" members

Comment: Aboodred: 60740 people are using the module. I'm pretty sure that I'm getting something wrong and that there is a way to do as suggestes by the module (see citation).
Chapabu: I know, that'd be much nicer. But upon email validation, LoginToboggan automatically removes the non-authenticated role and assigns "authenticated". If I set up "authenticated" as non-authenticated, then all users will remain non-authenticated after email verification.

Comment: @yaelsho's answer below actually gives you the functionality you're looking for.  You should mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't appear to be documented in the LoginToboggan interface anywhere but the default behaviour actually does what you want it to do.

You need to create new role like you mentioned, a `pre-authenticated user`. 
After creating the new role go to LoginToboggan config page and select this new role as your Non-authenticated role and save.
Now when you go back to the permission config page you'll see this new role is excluded from the `authenticated user` permissions, just like the `anonymous user`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules)

```
The rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally
executed  actions based on occurring events
```

You can create a rule that sets pre-authenticated role on registration and one rule that set another role after the user has confirmed it.

EDIT --------------

LoginToboggan has an option :

> **Non-authenticated role**
>
> If "Set password" is selected, users will be able to login before
>   their e-mail address has been authenticated. Therefore, you must
>   choose a role for new non-authenticated users -- you may wish to add a
>   new role for this purpose. Users will be removed from this role and
>   assigned to the "authenticated user" role once they follow the link in
>   their welcome e-mail. WARNING: changing this setting after initial
>   site setup can cause undesirable results, including unintended
>   deletion of users -- change with extreme caution!

Have you set your pre-authenticated role here?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I would like to use the functionality that LoginToboggan provides.

Comment: You can find some information here https://drupal.org/project/registration_toboggan . This module does not seem stable. If Login Toboggan does not provide this functionality you should use Rules.

Comment: This module advices me to do the same thing: _To use Registration Toboggan you are required to setup a pre-authorized roles within Logintoboggan to keep users with no password set and an un-verified email separate from normal users. Permissions associated with this role of user also must be super low pre-verification._

Comment: But it seems like there is no way to set up a role that has less permissions than "normal" users.

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: If I make "authenticated" my non-authenticated role, then users don't gain any permissions when they verify their email address, unless I use Rules module. I understand that using Rules would solve the issue, but I'm trying to point out a misconcept of LoginToboggan (or my misunderstanding of the module).

Comment: Since there is no way to add a _weaker_ role than "authenticated" and since users become "authenticated" upon verification, there is no way to let a gain of permissions happen upon email verification.

Comment: Sorry, I've just tested and that's my result. I've set up Loggin Toboggan with password: YES and Non-authenticated role as Mypreauthenticated. I've done a registration and I was logged in with Mypreautenthicated user role. Once I clicked the link on my email, I've gained the authenticated user role

Comment: Please try to give "Mypreauthenticated" _some_ permissions that "authenticated" has, but not all. My permissions table won't let me do this.

Comment: You should change the order of the roles. Click on the Roles tab and put preautenthicated user before Authenticated user and click save. Go back to the permission page and set the permissions.

Comment: I habe done that (see original post). It still inherits all authenticated permissions.

Comment: In my fresh drupal installation it works. I gave authenticated user the permission to Administer content and content type, I registered and I could not access to that page. Once I confirmed my registration, I got authenticated use role and now I can access to the admin content page. I'm able to set separate permission to preauthenticated and authenticated. Flush the cache again and again.

Comment: Turns out I first need to set "Mypreauthenticated" as the non-authenticated role in the LoginToboggan configurations and then set permissions for the role. Seems like LoginToboggan arranges that "Mypreauthenticated" doesn't inherit all permissions. This will be the case if I create the role and assign permissions right away.